# How to modify the php source code and recompile it?

Tags: php, compiler-construction, ubuntu

Hi for my research, i modify the c code that makes the php ( not the code that is written with php but that which actually makes php ). I want some way of compiling it and making it work with apache.. How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual is your friend:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --other-options
make
make install
```

Comment: I have been trying this for quite sometime..I have been trying this for quite sometime.. I get the error


"Sorry, I cannot run apxs. Possible reasons follow: 1. Perl is not installed 2. apxs was not found. Try to pass the path using --with- apxs2=/path/to/apxs 3. Apache was not built using --enable-so (the apxs usage page is displayed)"

Comment: locate apxs returns the following results

"/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/de/programs/apxs.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/en/programs/apxs.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/es/programs/apxs.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/fr/programs/apxs.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/ja/programs/apxs.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/ko/programs/apxs.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/pt-br/programs/apxs.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/tr/programs/apxs.html
"

Comment: Have you either build apache yourself, or installed an apache(-src/-devel) package? Have you installed Perl?

Comment: i did apt-get install apache2 for installing apache
I have not installed perl

Comment: Install either the  devel/src/dev package of aapache (I'm not sure how it would be called in your distro), and install `perl`

Comment: Hey Wrikken.. I don know why.. but the latest version(php-2.3.6) of php didnt work for me.. when I tried php-2.3.5 everything was fine..
THanks

Answer (score 1):

Grab a tarball of PHP source, and untar it.

Make sure you can compile it.  See the INSTALL file from the tarball.  The basic process is the typical:

```
./configure --with-some-options...
make
make install
```

That you're probably familiar with if you've ever compiled software from source on linux.

Make whatever changes you'd like to the source.

Compile again, using the same steps.