# PHP Mail does not add X-PHP-Script

Tags: php

I installed Ubuntu 22.04, php 8.1.2, Apache 2.4.52 and postfix. When I run test.php in browser with the code

```
mail($to, $subject, $body)
```

I receive the email without `X-PHP-Script` header. I expect to see

```
X-PHP-Script: <server_name><php_self> for <remote-addr>
```

After I set

```
mail.add_x_header = On
```

the header `X-PHP-Originating-Script` was added to a mail, but not `X-PHP-Script`. If I am not wrong, PHP mail always added `X-PHP-Script`.
I can add it manually via `additional_headers` parameter of `mail` function, but how to make PHP `mail` add it? What adds `X-PHP-Script` on my shared server with cPanel?

Comment: It's been `X-PHP-Originating-Script` since [it was added in 2009](https://web.archive.org/web/20090215034650/https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php).

Comment: There are many posts like 'how to remove X-PHP-Script?' I have a shared server with cPanel. When my script sends email, X-PHP-Script is in mail. So what adds X-PHP-Script and how to configure it on my cloud server?

Answer (score 2):

`X-PHP-Originating-Script` [is the header PHP adds (a commenter also mentioned that).](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.add-x-header)

This does not mean `X-PHP-Script` does not exist. cPanel, for instance, uses it to [identify messages](https://docs.cpanel.net/whm/service-configuration/exim-configuration-manager-basic-editor/#mail) sent by the `nobody` user. You may have seen the `X-PHP-Script` header, but it was not added by PHP itself.

cPanel itself adds this header internally. You may alter this behavior by using the [Exim Configuration Manager Advanced Editor](https://docs.cpanel.net/whm/service-configuration/exim-configuration-manager/#advanced-editor) in cPanel. One such way is to use [system-wide message filtering](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-systemwide_message_filtering.html#SECTaddremheasys). However, cPanel's documentation does **not** recommend doing so. It may cause ***severe performance issues*** or cause email messaging to ***stop working*** entirely.

This particular header is used to identify messages being delivered to Exim within cPanel. It is one of the possible ways to identify the source of a message to cPanel's mail transfer agent for **security purposes**. It is *unlikely* that shared server hosts will allow you to modify configurations of this type in cPanel.

It is possible to make PHP's `mail()` add it by:

- [modifying the PHP source and compiling it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097991/how-to-modify-the-php-source-code-and-recompile-it)
- [redefining the mail function using runkit7_function_redefine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit7-function-redefine.php)
- wrapping `mail()` in another function and using your newly
  constructed function

Modifying PHP's source and using `runkit7_function_redefine` are ***possible*** but ***not generally a feasible or appropriate way*** to change the behavior of PHP's `mail()`. They also require advanced knowledge and significant planning and effort.

Also, a mail transfer agent like [Exim Internet Mailer](https://www.exim.org/) can be configured to add or remove message headers outside of PHP, but this does not modify the behavior of `mail()` itself.

There is currently no simple way (as of 2023) to add `X-PHP-Script` automatically from within PHP, other than by doing it manually as you mentioned.

Comment: I updated my question in the post. On my other shared server, what adds X-PHP-Script header? Can I configure it in cPanel?

Comment: There's a fly in your bedroom that you want to get rid of. Do you use: 1) a nuclear bomb, 2) an RPG, or 3) a flyswatter? Your answer is certainly not wrong, but I wouldn't even offer the first two options, except maybe as a funny thought experiment.

Comment: @Duroth  It is still important to mention them because they are possible. I agree they are vast overkill, but when answering we're supposed to try to avoid opinions. I did add a generalized warning/explanation without going too far into opinion territory.

Comment: @vvkatwssvvkatwss It would be helpful if you explained why you need that particular header, and what the circumstances are. I'm not sure if that should be here or in a new question. If you have a particular problem you're trying to solve, explaining the particulars will help people understand your problem and offer more specific solutions.

Comment: @Joseph I have a website on HostGator. I allow some people to send emails from it. Some emails are not delivered with error "550 Connection Rejected - see http://www.spamhaus.org". This is because the header X-PHP-Script I guess. I run a cloud server and I want to send it also. I want to know what adds it on HostGator. I thought it php:mail, but maybe exim?